# Go. Узнать имя файла функции по указателю на функцию

Tags: golang

Возможно ли в Go узнать имя файла в котором определена функция по указателю на эту функцию?
Знаю, что есть runtime.Caller  для получения информации по вызываемым функциям... но если мы ничего не вызываем - просто есть слайс с указателями на функции. И хочется узнать имена их файлов, так как имена самих функций **New** и не обладают нужной информативностью.

Объясню для чего:
В коде используются множество midlleware, например:
"github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2/middleware/csrf"

Middleware вызывается как csrf.New() и имея указатель на этот обработчик (в слайсе Handlers для каждого конкретного Route) я могу узнать только имя самой функции. Но это имя не говорит о том какой именно обработчик используется для этого маршрута. Тогда как имя файла вполне специфично. Вот его то и хотелось бы как-то достать...

Answer (score 1):

Не имя исходного файла, но имя пакета + имя функции я получил. (код funcAddr был честно украден с хабра :-))

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
    "runtime"
    "reflect"
)


// funcAddr returns function value fn executable code address.
func funcAddr(fn interface{}) uintptr {
    // emptyInterface is the header for an interface{} value.
    type emptyInterface struct {
        typ   uintptr
        value *uintptr
    }
    e := (*emptyInterface)(unsafe.Pointer(&fn))
    return *e.value
}

func Func(fn interface{}) *runtime.Func {
    return runtime.FuncForPC(funcAddr(fn))
}
// а так будет попроще 
func funcAddr2(fn interface{}) uintptr {
    return reflect.ValueOf(fn).Pointer()
}

func Func2(fn interface{}) *runtime.Func {
    return runtime.FuncForPC(funcAddr2(fn))
}


func main() {
    fn := runtime.FuncForPC
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", fn)
    fmt.Println(Func(fn).Name())  // runtime.FuncForPC
    
}
```

Дальше уже можно сделать split для разделения на имя модуля и имя файла.
В случае модулей с гитхаба имя модуля придется укорачивать до последнего сегмента.

Comment: Круто! Для Go возможным является то, что для языков C/C++, кажется, невозможно